# standalone spark cluster unable to read hdfs from executor on kerberized cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, kerberos, hdp

Spark 3.x or 2.3
HDP 2.7
After enabling kerberos on HDP cluster, spark standalone cluster is unable to read data from hdfs and hive external tables, it is able to read metastore of hive.
If I run this spark-submit with master local, it reads data from hdfs and hive but after specifying master i.e spark-submit --master spark://:7077 abc.py

ERROR:

```
An error occurred while calling o29.csv.
: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]; Host Details : local host is: "node2.hadoop.com/10.x.x.x"; destination host is: "master1.hadoop.com":8020; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:776)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.isDirectory(FileSystem.java:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:308)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:796)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1746)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(Client.java:651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:738)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1452)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:561)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1900(Client.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:726)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1746)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:726)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:162)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:189)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
    ... 47 more
```

HDP Nodes master1 and node1
spark nodes node2(master) & node1(worker)

tried following ways:
spark-submit --master spark://node2:7077 --deploy-mode client abc.py

spark-submit --master spark://node2:7077 --keytab /tmp/sudhir.keytab --principal sudhir@EXAMPLE.COM ~/abc.

spark-submit --master spark://node2:7077 --deploy-mode client --conf spark.kerberos.keytab=/tmp/sudhir.keytab --conf spark.kerberos.principal=sudhir@EXAMPLE.COM ~/abc.py

with this also --conf spark.kerberos.access.hadoopFileSystems=hdfs://master1:8020

Comment: You seem to be doing reasonable things.  You need to find out where the breakdown is.  Here's some general troubleshooting suggestions.  use your keytab to `kinit` on master and node2.  see if that provides any information.   check the keytabs for master and node2 and make sure they match the hostname.  Check the hostname reverse lookup also shows the same name as the keytab.(on master & node2)

Comment: Thanks Matt, these all above points are matching