# Standalone Spark cluster can't access secure Hadoop by Kerberos

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, kerberos, hive-metastore

The symptom is similar to [standalone spark cluster unable to read hdfs from executor on kerberized cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73648850/standalone-spark-cluster-unable-to-read-hdfs-from-executor-on-kerberized-cluster) but have different error messages.

The setup is a Spark 3.3.1 based standalone cluster (1 master and 3 workers). Hadoop 3.3.2 cluster is configured with Kerberos. Using Hive Metastore 3.0.0 as Spark session catalog and a Iceberg catalog.

Secure Hadoop access works fine that application side (client) can access (read/write) Hadoop with keytab. Hive Metastore is working fine with a configured principal (hive/fqdn).

Use same principal that can access Hadoop to kinit and verified OK with klist.

Because I am not sure I fully understand how Spark can pass Kerberos TGT from client or server to Hadoop namenode, so I tried two different configs:

The first is configure `spark.kerberos.keytab` and `spark.kerberos.principal` in `spark-defaults.conf` on Spark master and each worker with super user `hdfs/fqdn`. This should be enough to let spark access hadoop. Then use spark-sql with and without keytab/principal to conduct queries.

The second is leave `spark-defaults.conf` without those configurations, instead pass `--keytab` and `--principal` with `spark-sql`.

The results are as below:

- starts spark-sql ok
- create table ok
- truncate table ok
- show create table, show tables ok

But insert (and other DML statements) fail, select fails. The error messages are as below:

1. `Can't get Master Kerberos principal for use as renewer` when `spark.kerberos.keytab` and `spark.kerberos.principal` are configured on spark master and workers.
2. `Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]` when spark master and workers do not have kerberos settings. Instead I pass keytab and principal with CLI options to spark-sql.
3. `SIMPLE authentication is not enabled` when spark master and workers do not have kerberos settings and spark-sql is run without keytab and principal but `kinit` is done.

FYI, unless standalone is impossible, YARN is not a choice at this moment. Also I have put hadoop config files including `core-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml` and `hive-site.xml` into spark conf directory.

Test spark-sql with local mode get similar result. But one strange result from local mode is the failure is only limited to hive format tables. DML and query on Iceberg tables did work. Just because local mode does not scale, it almost meets the expectation.

I would like to know if Spark deployed in standalone cluster does support access secure Hadoop (with Kerberos)? If yes, are there any links that point to some real examples? If access to secure Hadoop is impossible with Spark standalone cluster, what is the practical way for Spark to access a secure Hadoop in any way?

Thanks

Comment: did you figure out the problem? I have a similar one.